# Springboot: Spring JPA - How to get datasource properties from server container

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I use WAS Liberty Server container which provides server.xml and server.env file for configuring many things in addition to configuring DataSource properties such as url, username, password etc.

For security reasons, these properties are not known to developers for production Liberty servers.  However, developers use same server.xml/server.evn files but with different DataSource properties so they can do their work.

So, I might have two server.env files like:

```
PRODUCTION server.env: dataSourceUrl="server-A-URL" (this URL is not known to developers)
DEVELOPMENT server.env: dataSourceUrl="server-B-URL" (this URL is known to developers)
```

, then the `dataSourceUrl` is used in server.xml files in production and development to set the url accordingly.

So, the structure of server.xml/server.env file is same for developers and production, only the DataSource url, username, password are different.  This way developers can work using their own DataSource properties and once ready to deploy they app, it is handed to other team which then just changes the DataSource properties to the production values and deploys the application to production server.

With Springboot JPA, I know we can use application.properties file to set these DataSource values.  But, we would like to be able to set these to the values located in server.env file.  Basically to have something like this in application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=dataSourceUrl //dataSourceUrl is set in server.env
```

, then be able to use this value in Java code using @Value injection like:

```
public class MyClass {
   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   String dsUrl;
   ...
}
```

I have been reading about externalizing properties but I am not able to figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use Liberty's `jndiEntry` elements to make configured values available in JNDI.  You will need the `jndi-1.0` feature, after which you can configure,

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="spring/datasource/url" value="${dataSourceUrl}"/>
```

and access it in your application as:

```
String dsUrl = InitialContext.doLookup("spring/datasource/url");
```

Or, from a web or ejb component as:

```
@Resource(lookup = "spring/datasource/url")
String dsUrl;
```

Comment: Thank you @njr but this means the `dataSourceUrl` would not be defined at all in application.properties, only in `jndiEntry` element in server.xml and then app would use it through context lookup or `@Resource` annotation?  Am I correct?

Comment: Correct, the above assumes that you define dataSourceUrl in server.env (or as a variable in server.xml), not application.properties.  It looks like I misinterpreted that detail from your question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, the reason I make this important is that I use JPA.  So I shouldn't need to get that through context or '@Resource' annotation and initialize dataSource etc as JPA does all that automatically by reading these values from application.properties file